# Ionic Plugins.Storage does not have web implementation

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

Thats the error im having in an **Ionic+Angular project when I test it in chrome browser**.

The steps i followed so far:

```
ionic start testApp (with angular and blank choices)
ng build
ionic capacitor add android
ionic serve
```

Everything ok until here. Now if I try to store and retrieve some information from storage:

**home.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeService } from './home.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit{

  constructor(private homeService: HomeService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    debugger;
    this.homeService.setStoredUser().then( storedData => {
      debugger;
      console.log('Stored: '+storedData);
      this.homeService.getStoredUser().then( storedData => {
        debugger;
        console.log('Retrieved: '+storedData);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

**home.service.ts** (added to app.module.ts in provided array)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

@Injectable()
export class HomeService {

    constructor(private platform: Platform) {}

    getStoredUser() {
        let p = null;
        try {
            debugger;
            console.log(this.platform);
            p = Plugins.Storage.get({key: 'authData'});
            console.log(p);
        } catch (error) {
            debugger;
            console.log(error);
        }
        return p;
    }

    setStoredUser() {
        let p = null;
        try {
            debugger;
            console.log(this.platform);
            p = Plugins.storage.set({key: 'authData', value: 'Hello!'});
            console.log(p);
        } catch (error) {
            debugger;
            console.log(error);
        }
        return p;
    }

}
```

And here is the error in developer console:

```
> ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: 0, __zone_symbol__value:
> "storage does not have web implementation."}__zone_symbol__state:
> false__zone_symbol__value: "storage does not have web
> implementation."Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): (...)__proto__: Object
> core.js:9110 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): storage does not have
> web implementation.
>     at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
>     at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
>     at zone-evergreen.js:858
>     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
>     at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:34182)
>     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
>     at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
>     at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)
```

Any ideas of what i'm doing wrong or what i miss?

Answer (score 0):

In the case that someone faces the same problem. Found a working version of Storage plugin with the latests versions of Angular and Ionic.

Same example as before, but changing the service for this other one class and the consequent changes in the component:

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';

const { Storage } = Plugins;

export async function set(key: string, value: any): Promise<void> {
  await Storage.set({
    key: key,
    value: JSON.stringify(value)
  });
}

export async function get(key: string): Promise<any> {
  const item = await Storage.get({ key: key });
  return JSON.parse(item.value);
}

export async function remove(key: string): Promise<void> {
  await Storage.remove({
    key: key
  });
}
```

I don't know why this works for me and the first example not.